# Flex can't handle Java socket data quickly enough

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm sending through a socket from java to flex client some data and the flex side can't seem to handle it right.
In the java i'm looping over 8 objects and for each object I create a long string 1:lsls:2:3:justexample then the java does writeToSocket("1:lsls:2:3:justexample") for every iteration of the loop.
But in the client side, it seems that only 2 out of the 8 arrived. what can be the problem? 
Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like you're either sending or reading the data wrong – it shouldn't get lost like that. Can't tell without seeing the code that does the reading and writing though.

Comment: Have you used a tool, such as ServiceCapture, Charles, or the Flash Builder network monitor to see what is being passed to Flex?  Can you share any code?  How does Flex connect to the backend socket?

Comment: Impossible to comment without seeing the reading and writing code. All that can be said is that they don't agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your client does not read the data fast enough it is possible that the connection is prematurely reset by the Java side - if you `close()` the socket after sending that is. You could try [setSoLinger()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoLinger%28boolean,%20int%29) to allow more time for transmission of queued data before the connection is actually closed.